# php/jquery buffer full? page not completely loading

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that I am currently writing that is hosted on a singleboard computer. The current webpage that I am coding is used to setup the timezone and current time settings of the board. It features jquery items, javascript functions, a form with 3 submit buttons, php scripts, and a few linux command line exec calls being run, to change the timezone of the board from the commandline. I am also doing more than a handful of string comparisons when determining what the default dropdown item selection should be.

The issue I am having is very repeatable. If I submit the time zone, then change the time, set the time zone again, change the time again, and maybe repeat this one more time, the page doesn't completely load. Upon viewing the source, it is clear that the entire page is not being loaded completely. Usually it ends of failing somewhere within the dropdown selection creation.

For example, this is at the very bottom of the loaded source code file when it fails:

```
<input class="button" type="submit" name="getLocalTime" value="Copy Local Time"><br><br><br><table><tr><td colspan="2"><tr><td>

<select name="DropDownTimezone" id="DropDownTimezone">
<option  value="Etc/GMT+12">(GMT -12:00) Eniwetok, Kwajalein</option>
<option  value="Etc/GMT+11">(GMT -11:00) Midway Island, Samoa</option>
<option  value="Etc/GMT+10">(GMT -10:00) Hawaii</option>
<option  value="Etc/GMT+9">(GMT -9:00) Alaska</option>
<option  value="Etc/GMT+8">(GMT -8:00) Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada)</option>
<option  value="Etc/GMT+7">(GMT -7:00)
```

That section is coded like this:

```
<select name="DropDownTimezone" id="DropDownTimezone">
<option <?php if ($hwOffset == "-12") echo 'selected'; ?> value="Etc/GMT+12">(GMT -12:00) Eniwetok, Kwajalein</option>
<option <?php if ($hwOffset == "-11") echo 'selected'; ?> value="Etc/GMT+11">(GMT -11:00) Midway Island, Samoa</option>
<option <?php if ($hwOffset == "-10") echo 'selected'; ?> value="Etc/GMT+10">(GMT -10:00) Hawaii</option>
<option <?php if ($hwOffset == "-9") echo 'selected'; ?> value="Etc/GMT+9">(GMT -9:00) Alaska</option>
<option <?php if ($hwOffset == "-8") echo 'selected'; ?> value="Etc/GMT+8">(GMT -8:00) Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada)</option>
<option <?php if ($hwOffset == "-7") echo 'selected'; ?> value="Etc/GMT+7">(GMT -7:00) Mountain Time (US &amp; Canada)</option>
<option <?php if ($hwOffset == "-6") echo 'selected'; ?> value="Etc/GMT+6">(GMT -6:00) Central Time (US &amp; Canada), Mexico City</option>
<option <?php if ($hwOffset == "-5") echo 'selected'; ?> value="Etc/GMT+5">(GMT -5:00) Eastern Time (US &amp; Canada), Bogota, Lima</option>
<option <?php if ($hwOffset == "-4") echo 'selected'; ?> value="Etc/GMT+4">(GMT -4:00) Atlantic Time (Canada), Caracas, La Paz</option>
<option <?php if ($hwOffset == "-3") echo 'selected'; ?> value="Etc/GMT+3">(GMT -3:00) Brazil, Buenos Aires, Georgetown</option>
<option <?php if ($hwOffset == "-2") echo 'selected'; ?> value="Etc/GMT+2">(GMT -2:00) Mid-Atlantic</option>
<option <?php if ($hwOffset == "-1") echo 'selected'; ?> value="Etc/GMT+1">(GMT -1:00) Azores, Cape Verde Islands</option>
<option <?php if ($hwOffset == "+0") echo 'selected'; ?> value="Etc/GMT+0">(GMT) Western Europe Time, London, Lisbon, Casablanca</option>
<option <?php if ($hwOffset == "+1") echo 'selected'; ?> value="Etc/GMT-1">(GMT +1:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris</option>
<option <?php if ($hwOffset == "+2") echo 'selected'; ?> value="Etc/GMT-2">(GMT +2:00) Kaliningrad, South Africa</option>
<option <?php if ($hwOffset == "+3") echo 'selected'; ?> value="Etc/GMT-3">(GMT +3:00) Baghdad, Riyadh, Moscow, St Petersburg</option>
<option <?php if ($hwOffset == "+4") echo 'selected'; ?> value="Etc/GMT-4">(GMT +4:00) Abu Dhabi, Muscat, Baku, Tbilisi</option>
<option <?php if ($hwOffset == "+5") echo 'selected'; ?> value="Etc/GMT-5">(GMT +5:00) Ekaterinburg, Islamabad, Karachi, Tashkent</option>
<option <?php if ($hwOffset == "+6") echo 'selected'; ?> value="Etc/GMT-6">(GMT +6:00) Almaty, Dhaka, Colombo</option>
<option <?php if ($hwOffset == "+7") echo 'selected'; ?> value="Etc/GMT-7">(GMT +7:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta</option>
<option <?php if ($hwOffset == "+8") echo 'selected'; ?> value="Etc/GMT-8">(GMT +8:00) Beijing, Perth, Singapore, Hong Kong</option>
<option <?php if ($hwOffset == "+9") echo 'selected'; ?> value="Etc/GMT-9">(GMT +9:00) Tokyo, Seoul, Osaka, Sapporo, Yakutsk</option>
<option <?php if ($hwOffset == "+10") echo 'selected'; ?> value="Etc/GMT-10">(GMT +10:00) Eastern Australia, Guam, Vladivostok</option>
<option <?php if ($hwOffset == "+11") echo 'selected'; ?> value="Etc/GMT-11">(GMT +11:00) Magadan, Solomon Islands, New Caledonia</option>
<option <?php if ($hwOffset == "+12") echo 'selected'; ?> value="Etc/GMT-12">(GMT +12:00) Auckland, Wellington, Fiji, Kamchatka</option>
</select>
```

I am thinking that this has something to do with memory running out or a buffer filling up, since it does not fail every time, but will fail after roughly the same number of repeated steps. Are there any useful commands in PHP or methods to avoid having this issue? Or are there any other possible root causes for problems like this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @minitech : http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135066/155556

Comment: No errors are appearing to be logged when this happens.

Comment: Btw, I don't mean to be rude, but the coding is horrible, why don't you use loops and arrays to clean it up a bit?

Comment: Yep, it's pretty horrible right now. I plan to make it into an array loop once I incorporate translations and get it functioning correctly. The ugly inline-php was also an attempted fix to my issue, rather than using strcmp function calls.

Comment: Do the page stop loading always at the same point, or it varies? e.g.: when it gets to `<option <?php if ($hwOffset == "-7") echo 'selected'; ?> value="Etc/GMT+7">(GMT -7:00)` it stops every time?

Comment: Have you tried enabling error reporting with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` also check that error reporting is enabled in your `php.ini`. Tho your code could be cleaned up the snippet you have provided would not be causing any memory issue.

Comment: It fails roughly around that spot each time, unless the timezone is set to anything before -7. So, if it is set to -8 or -9, it fails shortly after that.

My mistake, I double checked the error log with it live scrolling and found the line.(mod_fastcgi.c.2699) FastCGI-stderr: PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home/www/station4/include/contentsHome.php on line 60 PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in /home/www/station4/include/contentsHome.php on

Comment: Fix it and then let us know its now working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, and embarrassingly, this issue was related to my form code and had little to do with the timezone dropdown, it just coincidentally failed around there every time. Thank you all for the input on the issue, since it did indeed point my in the right direction (and made me feel stupid haha). Once I started tracking down possible broken variables, I noticed that my form action= item was pointing to a variable to get the filename. I soon realized that the filename had not been set after monitoring the error log for a little while. Once I cleaned that line up, it seemed to fix my other issues strangely enough.

Before: `echo "<form method='POST' action='".$PHP_SELF."' onsubmit='getTime();'>";`

After: `echo "<form method='POST' action='?page=home' onsubmit='getTime();'>";`

And this appears to have fixed it. I'm a bit confused as to why it was still submitting, and why it was failing in the manner that it was, but this line appears to have fixed any partially loaded pages that were occurring.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to as of why this happens (as your code looks fine, although ugly, and as others have mentioned, try with `error_reporting(E_ALL)`). Is this what you receive with jQuery, or is this the HTML output when you load the site?

As an add-on, here's an array version of your code where you should be able to easily incorporate your translations.

```
<?php
    $timezones = array(
        'Eniwetok, Kwajalein',
        'Midway Island, Samoa',
        'Hawaii',
        'Alaska',
        'Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada)',
        'Mountain Time (US &amp; Canada)',
        'Central Time (US &amp; Canada), Mexico City',
        'Eastern Time (US &amp; Canada), Bogota, Lima',
        'Atlantic Time (Canada), Caracas, La Paz',
        'Brazil, Buenos Aires, Georgetown',
        'Mid-Atlantic',
        'Azores, Cape Verde Islands',
        'Western Europe Time, London, Lisbon, Casablanca',
        'Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris',
        'Kaliningrad, South Africa',
        'Baghdad, Riyadh, Moscow, St Petersburg',
        'Abu Dhabi, Muscat, Baku, Tbilisi',
        'Ekaterinburg, Islamabad, Karachi, Tashkent',
        'Almaty, Dhaka, Colombo',
        'Bangkok, HanoiBeijing, Perth, Singapore, Hong Kong, Jakarta',
        'Beijing, Perth, Singapore, Hong Kong',
        'Tokyo, Seoul, Osaka, Sapporo, Yakutsk',
        'Eastern Australia, Guam, Vladivostok',
        'Magadan, Solomon Islands, New Caledonia',
        'Auckland, Wellington, Fiji, Kamchatka'
    );
    echo '<select name="DropDownTimezone" id="DropDownTimezone">';
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($timezones); $i++) {
        $timezone = ($i - 12);
        $timezoneReverse = ($timezone * -1);
        $timezoneValue = ($timezone >= 0 ? '+' . $timezone : $timezone);
        $timezoneReverseValue = ($timezoneReverse >= 0 ? '+' . $timezoneReverse : $timezoneReverse);
        echo '<option' . ($hwOffset == $timezoneValue ? ' selected' : '') . ' value="Etc/GMT' . $timezoneReverseValue . '">(GMT' . ($timezone != 0 ? ' ' . $timezoneValue . ':00' : '') . ') ' . $timezones[$i] . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
?>
```

*Please note, that this probably won't actually fix your problem, so please don't accept it as a solution, as it's merely an edit of your HTML, but it was a too big change for me to want to edit your OP*

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this, it will be useful. As far as the output, that is like if I load the webpage itself, and click view source on the page. It is incomplete.

Comment: You mentioned some offset errors - what do the lines look like on those lines? (Not that it should actually matter, as they're PHP Notices and shouldn't make a page stop rendering). Try to use the `tail -f` command on your PHP log, maybe with a `tail -f PHPLOGPATH | grep Warning`

Comment: `$splitLink = preg_split("/([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}[ ]| ->  /",$commandline[$i]);` and `$appName = $splitLink[1];` are the lines that deal with that error code. The line checks the system for existing symlinks using a ls -l call. This offset issue may deal with poor coding on my part, I'm in the process of debugging it right now.

Comment: Remember to let us now if you figure out whether or not that was the problem. :)

Comment: Figured out my issue, and posted an answer about it. Thank you very much for your help in this, and thank you for coding that dropdown out for me, I will definitely be incorporating it in.